# AEM 6.0 SP1 Remote SolR Instance issue

Tags: solr, aem

I've been trying to get AEM 6.0 SP1 to connect to a remote SolR server for quite a while and I'm at a point where I think that Adobe's own documentation is lacking a specific step somewhere.

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/queries-and-indexing.html

I configured everything following the steps at:
Configuring AEM with a single remote SOLR server

But 1st issue I had was that when starting the 1st shard, Zookeep kept saying it couldn't find the solr//zoo.cfg.
So I created the solr folder within node1 and copied the solr.xml and zoo.cfg into it.

starting with
java -Xmx2g -Dbootstrap_confdir=".\cfg\oak\conf" -Dcollection.configName=myconf -DzkRun -DnumShards=2 -jar start.jar

seems to start the shard correctly now with this, but there's no OAK core, even though they say to copy the zookeeper and solrconfig into the cfg folder.

in the cfg, I unpacked the content of recommended-conf.zip

I followed their steps completely, and AEM still can't connect to the SolR instance, it returns an error about getting HTML instead of octet/stream.  (and obviously, there's no OAK core)

what am I missing here? This is on a windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the "Solr HTTP URL" and "ZooKeeper host" fields in the "Oak Solr remote server configuration" at http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr ?

We set the

Solr HTTP URL to http://localhost:8983/solr/

and the ZooKeeper host to http://localhost:9983

Comment: Yes, I did, same errors, it keeps trying to connect to urls that are not valid.  like /solr/oak gives a 404   or /solr/admin/ping which also gives a 404.   Like I said, the documentation on Adobe's site is clearly incomplete, or they should at least say which exact version of SolR they're expecting us to be using if it has to be a specific one.   The whole AEM 6 experience with indexing has been a huge frustration so far though.

Comment: Which Solr Version are you using then? I've only gotten it to work with 4.10.4 but not 5.0

Comment: Was using 4.9.1  (5.0 I know that their own recommended conf isn't compatible because it used deprecated entities types)  But looking at their forum, there's a thread from December that makes it look like it might actually be a bug with SP1 (wouldn't be the 1st)

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know this. I'm running AEM6 SP2

Comment: for us, the search component stopped working completely when moving to SP2 (amongs other issues), so we stayed on SP1 for now.